# vim change newline into space but not every nth-line

Tags: vim, newline, substitution

I have a file.txt of 1000 lines and every first 10 lines need to be on one line.
The eleventh line starts on a new line and is added with lines 12-20.

How can I do this in **Vim!**

Comment: Does it have to be `vim`? Why not something like `awk`?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I grok what you're after, but I'll give you a few hints and perhaps they'll help.

To join lines together you can use J (that's capital J or Shift-J). You can precede this with a number, such as 10, and join 10 lines together. For example, typing `10J` will give you:

[image]

Now, what you really need is a macro. This sounds fancy but it's just a way or recording a set of commands. So for example you could take `10J` and record it to a macro. Repeat that macro 10 times and then you do that to 100 lines.

I think that the solution to your problem would therefore be something like this:

```
qa10Jjjq99@a
```

This does this (see below for an explanation):

[image]

Explanation:

`q` starts recording a macro. Everything that you type afterwards, until you type `q` again will be recorded. The next character `a` records the macro to the character a. Thus, `qa` of `qa10Jjjq99@a`records `10Jjj` to `a`. Now, to use the macro that you have stored to `a` you use the `@` symbol followed by the letter of where you stored the macro (in this case `a`, because we typed `qa`). The `99` means repeat this 99 times, thus, `99@a` means repeat what's stored in macro a 99 times.

All together `qa10Jjjq99@a` means: record a macro `q` and store it in `a`. Then, join 10 lines `10J` and move down two lines `jj` before stopping the recording `q`. Then repeat the macro stored 99 times `99@a`.